# React json - passing id from json and value from react componet

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a React component, that needs to display static text followed by dynamically calculated value.

```
 displayContent={[
              { id: 'mangoes', value: total.mango },
              { id: 'apples', value: total.apples },
            ]}
```

I am getting the id from a json file that has all ids(static). But values are calculated dynamically.

The proptypes for displayContent is array of shape as below :

```
 displayContent: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
id: PropTypes.string,
value: PropTypes.string,
```

})),

But this doesnt work, can u help what is wrong here